# How to write a "for loop" in the most efficient way (the fastest execution)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I've got this code:

```
all_sorted = [['9', 's'], ['11', 'h'], ['2', 's'], ['13', 'c'], ['13', 's'], ['11', 's'], ['3', 'd']]
pairness = {str(i): 0 for i in range(14, 1, -1)}
for card in all_sorted:
    pairness[card[0]] += 1
```

Is it possible to write 2nd-4th lines of code in 1 more efficient line?

Comment: Does order matters?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter

Comment: So why the range backwards?

Comment: It's easier for further implementation but it's not necessary

Comment: why do you think less lines of code means more efficient?

Comment: you're right Manu, I'll change the topic name

Comment: Define 'efficient'. Efficient *how*? More readable? Then don't put anything on a single line. Or more memory or CPU efficient?

Comment: I meant least time consuming

Answer (score 3):

Shorter, but I don't know how much faster (probably not much, if at all)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(x for x, _ in all_sorted)
Counter({'11': 2, '13': 2, '9': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1})
```

Comment: The `map` function is slower than the list comprehension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: Not a bad approach, assuming that it's not strictly necessary to display all the keys that have a count of zero. I wouldn't worry about speed, since looping once over a list with ten elements is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Is it possible with list comprehension?

Comment: List comprehensions produce lists, and the result you want is a dict. So no, you can't do this with _just_ a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

A version using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that creates the keys with zero values (matching the expected output):

```
from collections import Counter

all_sorted = [['9', 's'], ['11', 'h'], ['2', 's'], ['13', 'c'], ['13', 's'], ['11', 's'], ['3', 'd']]
pairness = {**{str(i): 0 for i in range(14, 1, -1)}, **Counter(head for head, *_ in all_sorted)}

print(pairness)
```

**Output**

```
{'8': 0, '11': 2, '14': 0, '4': 0, '12': 0, '3': 1, '2': 1, '13': 2, '5': 0, '10': 0, '7': 0, '6': 0, '9': 1}
```